# How can I print a newline as \n in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell

Basically, I want to achieve something like the inverse of `echo -e`.

I have a variable which stores a command output, but I want to print newlines as \n.

Comment: Does the variable contain literal `\n`s or actual newlines that you want to convert to `\n`s?

Comment: @Biffen The variable contains actual newlines.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the inverse of `echo -e` would also involve translating _additional_ control chars. into their escape sequences, such as tabs to `'\t'`. Based on the accepted answer, however, it seems that handling newlines is sufficient in this case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```
sed 's/$/\\n/' | tr -d '\n'
```

Comment: That's simpler than the awk solution. I'll accept this one.

Comment: +1 - clever; as with the `awk` solution, you always get a trailing literal `\n` sequence; unlike with `awk`, however, suppressing it is simple: `sed '$! s/$/\\n/'`.

Answer (score 8):

If your **input** is already in a *(Bash) shell variable*, say `$varWithNewlines`:

```
echo "${varWithNewlines//$'\n'/\\n}"
```

It simply uses Bash [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#search_and_replace) to replace all newline (`$'\n'`) instances with literal `'\n'` each.

---

If your **input** comes from a **file**, use AWK:

```
awk -v ORS='\\n' 1
```

In action, with sample input:

```
# Sample input with actual newlines created with ANSI C quoting ($'...'),
# which turns `\n` literals into actual newlines.
varWithNewlines=$'line 1\nline 2\nline 3'

# Translate newlines to '\n' literals.
# Note the use of `printf %s` to avoid adding an additional newline.
# By contrast, a here-string - <<<"$varWithNewlines" _always appends a newline_.
printf %s "$varWithNewlines" | awk -v ORS='\\n' 1
```

- `awk` reads input line by line
- by setting `ORS`- the *output* record separator to literal `'\n'` (escaped with an additional `\` so that `awk` doesn't interpret it as an escape sequence), the input lines are output with that separator
- `1` is just shorthand for `{print}`, i.e., all input lines are printed, terminated by `ORS`.

Note: The *output will always end in literal* `'\n'`, *even if your input does not end in a newline*.

This is because AWK terminates *every* output line with `ORS`, whether the input line ended with a newline (separator specified in `FS`) or not.

---

Here's how to *unconditionally* strip the terminating literal `'\n'` from your output.

```
# Translate newlines to '\n' literals and capture in variable.
varEncoded=$(printf %s "$varWithNewlines" | awk -v ORS='\\n' 1)

# Strip terminating '\n' literal from the variable value
# using Bash parameter expansion.
echo "${varEncoded%\\n}"
```

---

By contrast, more work is needed if you want to *make the presence of a terminating literal `'\n'` dependent on whether the input ends with a newline or not*.

```
# Translate newlines to '\n' literals and capture in variable.
varEncoded=$(printf %s "$varWithNewlines" | awk -v ORS='\\n' 1)

# If the input does not end with a newline, strip the terminating '\n' literal.
if [[ $varWithNewlines != *$'\n' ]]; then
  # Strip terminating '\n' literal from the variable value
  # using Bash parameter expansion.
  echo "${varEncoded%\\n}"
else
  echo "$varEncoded"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `printf "%q"`:

```
eol=$'\n'
printf "%q\n" "$eol"
$'\n'
```

Comment: Is there a way to not introduce the `$'` and `'` around the string?

Comment: Just to clarify: depending on input, `printf %q` will EITHER output an _overall_ _unquoted_ strings with _individual_ shell metacharacters `\ `-escaped, OR - if control characters such as newlines and _others too_ (e.g., tabs) are present - an ANSI C-quoted string (`$'...'`), as in the answer. The _purpose of `printf %`_ is to get a representation of a string that you can safely _use as command arguments_ or _variable values in source code_ - i.e., the output is usually NOT meant to be used literally.

Answer (score 1):

A Bash solution

```
x=$'abcd\ne fg\nghi'
printf "%s\n" "$x"
abcd
e fg
ghi
y=$(IFS=$'\n'; set -f; printf '%s\\n' $x)
y=${y%??}
printf "%s\n" "$y"
abcd\ne fg\nghi
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the unquoted reference to `$x` makes its value subject to pathname expansion, so that an input line such as `*` would yield unexpected results - you could include `set -f;` at the start of your subshell to suppress pathname expansion.

Comment: @mklement0, true enough. fixed