# How do I render escape characters .e.g \n and \t as new line and spaces in bash?

Tags: bash

I'd like the reverse of this

[How can I print a newline as \n in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23848294/how-can-i-print-a-newline-as-n-in-bash)

Basically I have a JSON with a stack trace embedded as string and I want to see it without the control characters

I tried `cat -e` and `echo -e` to no avail.

Note I am asking for both `\n` and `\t`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JQ how to print newline and not newline character from json value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32715008/jq-how-to-print-newline-and-not-newline-character-from-json-value). The answers there explain how to do this both with `jq` and with `sed`

Comment: If the json data contains `\\n` it means one literal backslash and one literal `n` so it's erroneously encoded if it's supposed to encode a newline. Where do you get the json data from? I'd tell them to fix the encoding issue.

Comment: If it's using JSON escaping rules, it's best to use something that knows how to parse that JSON properly (like `jq` as @Brian61354270 suggested) rather than hack something that only handles certain characters.

Comment: I'm not using JQ because I am just grabbing part of a JSON output.  Hence why I asked for Bash.

Answer (score 0):

The following command did the translation for me

```
sed 's/\\n/\n/g ; s/\\t/\t/g' -
```

Just have to note that you need to mark the end of your file (i.e. put <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> <kbd>enter</kbd> )

Comment: This produces invalid json.

Comment: I'm not trying to make JSON, I am extracting the content that is in JSON.

Comment: Then use `jq` to extract the value, then transform it. You can probably do the transformation in `jq` too. Had the json data been properly encoded no transformation had been needed and you could just use `jq` to extract it.